# Angular image add to array then post to API

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to build a system that you upload photos add photos to array, save photos. When you save photo it posts to a API, also the Array is per populated with the current images saved to the API on last visit.

So

1. User uploads photos and sees a preview (Working)
2. Click add and it adds the preview image to the array (Not Working)
3. Save updated array and post to API. (Working but dose not update array async)
4. Remove Image from array (Not working)

**In Summery**

I need a array of images that is pulled from a API and the images can be deleted and added then saved back to the API.

can anyone help me fix this, I belive the code is right but maybe a few errors or bugs in the code.

When I click add I get an error.

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

**My HTML**

```
<div class="dynamic-upload-container">
        <div class="preview"><img style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{preview}}" alt="preview image"></div>
        <div class="upload-new">
            <input id="fileinput" ng-model="file" type="file" ng-model-instant="" name="file" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)"> {{uploadError}}

        </div>
        <div class="slots-container">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><h3>there is a campaign</h3></th>
                    <th> <strong>{{campaign.c_name}}</strong></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h3>this is the max slots</h3></td>
                    <td><strong>{{campaign.max_slots}}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button ng-click="addImage()">Add image</button>

            <h3>this are the slots</h3> <strong>{{campaign.slots}}</strong>

                <div ng-repeat="slot in campaign.slots"  class="slot">
                    <img ng-click="addImage()" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{slot.base_image}}" alt="slot image">
                    <button ng-click="removeImage(slot)">Remove Image</button>
                <div>this is a slot</div>
            </div>

             <button ng-click="SaveImage()">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
.controller('Dashboard', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.campaigns =[];
    $scope.preview = 'img/download.png';
    $scope.slots = [];
    $scope.maxSlots = 5; // this dynamic


    $scope.debug = function(){
        console.log('this is debug');
        console.log($scope.slots.length);
    };

    $scope.uploadImage = function () {
        // console.log('we are here');
        input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
        file = input.files[0];
        size = file.size;
        if (size < 650000) {
            var fr = new FileReader;
            fr.onload = function (e) {
                var img = new Image;

                img.onload = function () {
                    var width = img.width;
                    var height = img.height;
                    if (width == 1920 && height == 1080) {
                        $scope.preview = e.target.result;
                        $scope.perfect = "you added a image";
                        $scope.$apply();

                    } else {
                        $scope.notPerfect = "incorrect definitions";
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                };
                img.src = fr.result;
            };

            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            $scope.notPerfect = "to big";
        }
    };

    $scope.addImage = function () {
        if ($scope.slots.length < $scope.maxSlots) {
            $scope.slots.push({
                "slot_id": $scope.slots.length + 1,
                "base_image": $scope.preview,
                "path_image": ""
            });
            $scope.$apply();

        } else {
            window.alert("you have to delete a slot to generate a new one");
            // console.log('you have to delete a slot to generate a new one')
        }
        // $scope.$apply()
    };

    $scope.SaveImage = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.site.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/updateSlots",
            method: "POST",
            data: { 'campaign': "ben", 'slots': $scope.slots },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('success');
            console.log("then : " + JSON.stringify(response));
            // location.href = '/cms/index.html';
        }, function (response) { // optional
            // failed
            console.log('failed');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    };

    $scope.removeImage = function(s) {
        $scope.slots.splice($scope.slots.indexOf(s), 1);
    };

    $scope.GetData = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.site.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/getCampaign",
            method: "POST",
            date: {},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('you have received the data ');
            console.log(response);


            $scope.campaigns = response.data;
            //$scope.slots = data.data[0].slots;

        }, function (response) {
            // failed
            console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

    $scope.GetData();
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't directly use the `$spply` method. Becuase if you trigger it within a digest cycle you'll get errors like above. Instead always use following `safeApply` method. Replace your all `$apply()` methods with

```
$scope.safeApply();
```

```js
/**
 * This method is to create a safe apply rather than triggering
 * the $apply method inside a digest circle.
 */
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  if (this.$root) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
      if (fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
        fn();
      }
    } else {
      this.$apply(fn);
    }
  } else {
    fn();
  }
};

//Use this anywhere instead of the inbuilt $scope.$apply() method.
//$scope.safeApply();
```

Comment: Thanks, ill add this function and see if it helps

Comment: seems to fix some problems, not all but some so ill accept and post a new question in regards to the rest that dose not work. thank you.